Samsung - upgrading operating system / MFA
I'm travelling at present and not using my "home" sim to avoid excessive roaming costs. I'm being prompted to upgrade my operating system on my phone and I understand there's an MFA requirement to do the upgrade. If I have to use MFA I expect I need to put my "home" sim back into the phone to receive the MFA code. Is this correct? Is there an alternative to receiving a text / having to put the sim back in?

Please only one question in a question post here. MFA is the name of a general technique. It can be implemented using SMS, but there are implementations that use different channels. What channels can be used depends on the software that uses MFA wo we can not answer this question. For software updates it depends. What device (model, manufacturer and where bought) do you have and which Android version?

I have had Samsung phones for years with various providers.  I have never had to use MFA to do a Phone upgrade.  MFA (or Multi Factor Authentication) is used to prove you are who you say you are.
A phone upgrade is not tied to the SIM, however upgrades are rolled out by region.  Putting a SIM back is not necessarily going to change the region.
If your phone is able to do the upgrade, let it do it.  If it really will not proceed without a SIM swap, it will probably fail because you are not in your home country.  So, do the upgrade when you get back.
